# Display bug on activity recycling

Tags: android, android-activity, android-framelayout, drawer

I need to make an Android app which use the same drawer. I found a tutorial on Internet and here is my source code:

My AppBaseActivity :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <FrameLayout
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:id="@+id/vue"
        android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Java AppBaseActivity :

```
package assistance.utils;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

import assistance.R;
import assistance.main.SearchActivity;
import assistance.main.SettingsActivity;

public abstract class AppBaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private FrameLayout vue;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.setContentView(R.layout.app_base_activity);
        vue = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.vue);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        super.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        toolbarSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.toolbarSearch);
        toolbarSearch.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
                //...
            }
        });

        toolbarSearch.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View view, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SearchActivity.class);
                view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                return false;
            }
        });

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void setContentView(int layoutResID){
        if (vue!=null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
            );
            View stubView = inflater.inflate(layoutResID, vue, false);
            vue.addView(stubView, lp);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setContentView(View view){
        if (vue!=null){
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
            );
            vue.addView(view, lp);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setContentView(View view, ViewGroup.LayoutParams params){
        if (vue!=null) {
            vue.addView(view,params);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this,SettingsActivity.class));
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

XML Main Activity :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="assistance.main.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="Evolution du chiffre d'affaires"
        android:background="@drawable/layout_rubrique_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.CombinedChart
        android:id="@+id/chart"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp" />

    <TextView
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="Affaires en cours"
        android:background="@drawable/layout_rubrique_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/opportunites" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Java Main Activity :

```
package assistance.main;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.github.mikephil.charting.animation.Easing;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.CombinedChart;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.components.AxisBase;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.components.Description;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.components.XAxis;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.components.YAxis;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.BarData;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.BarDataSet;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.BarEntry;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.CombinedData;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.Entry;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.LineData;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.LineDataSet;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.formatter.IAxisValueFormatter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import assistance.R;
import assistance.utils.AppBaseActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppBaseActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.setContentView(R.layout.content_main);
        //...
    }

}
```

And finally XML Search Activity :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/content_search"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="assistance.main.SearchActivity" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/seaRecords"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/seaResultats" />
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And java Search Activity :

```
package assistance.main;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.EditText;

import assistance.R;
import assistance.utils.AppBaseActivity;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SearchActivity extends AppBaseActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.setContentView(R.layout.content_search);
        //...
    }

}
```

I have my drawer on each activity, but when I open another activity from the main one, I have a problem: all elements added on my framelayout in the main activity stay on the screen, in front of the new elements...

Is there anyone to help me please?

[Main activity:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgVBf.png)

[Search activity:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSVYz.png)

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont override the setContentView() method.Instead create a different method to load your view.

```
public void addView(int layoutResID){
    if (vue!=null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
        ); 
        View stubView = inflater.inflate(layoutResID, vue, false);
        vue.addView(stubView, lp);
    } 
}
```

And inside your Main activity and Search activity call the method

```
@Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addView(R.layout.content_main);
    //... 
}
```

**EDIT:**
Also remove the app_bar_main and add views on the frame layout

```
<include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the problem is still relevant... :(

Comment: I need to remove my appBar on my baseActivity? If I do this, I have to add it on each activity?
Same problem if I add views directly to the frameLayout on my baseActivit?

Comment: you are adding views to frameLayout.app bar is useless and redundant

Comment: Problem is the same and now I don't have toolbar anymore :-s

Comment: what does appbar contains?move your toolbar out and add above frameLayout

Comment: or remove  that frame layout and keep this appbar..inside this appbar below toolbar wrap everything inside frame layout and use that as container.

Comment: Gotcha!!
Thanks a lot for your help!
I'd got this line in my "app_bar_main.xml":

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />

Just have to delete this line et everything is ok :-)